# Gatling Stress Tool

Tags: gatling

Just a quick question.  I am carrying out some tests using Gatling.  Is there any way that I can get it to perform a click action on a button or hyperlink / xpath?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatling is not a browser but an HTTP client, so it doesn't execute Javascript, it just sends HTTP requests and received HTTP responses.

So:

- "click action on a button" is a no. You have to find out (Gatling Recorder, firebug or whatever HTTP traffic sniffer) the underlying HTTP action.
- "hyperlink": you have to use a check (regex or css selector) to capture the href url.
- "xpath" is probably a no in the way you intend it. XPath works on a DOM tree, which is in the case of a browser the internal representation (parsed HTML + javascript DOM tree manipulations). Gatling XPath only works on well-formed XML, which standard HTML is not. You can use [CSS selectors](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.3/http/http_check.html?highlight=css%20selectors).